# Updating span with a variable from localstorage

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to replace the text in my html span with a variable from another script
I know the variable is being passed right since it shows up in the console but no matter what I try i can't get the text to  update
Anyone have any ideas  how to fix this?

````
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
    ready()
}
function ready()
{
    window.onload(console.log(localStorage.getItem("total")))
    costUpdate()
}


function costUpdate ()
{
    var cost = localStorage.getItem("total")
    getElementById("cost-text").textContent = '$' + cost
} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I removed *window.onload* from window.onload(console.log(localStorage.getItem("total")))```
I'm not sure why this worked or how it was interfering so I'll mark this as solved but if someone could explain this to me it'd be appreciated.